# How to properly use adjustSize() in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface

I'm new to Qt, and this issue about auto resizing has driven me crazy.

I create a class called `RenderArea` that inherits `QWidget`. In its `paintEvent()`, I use a `QPainter` to draw an image. In order for the whole window to scale with the image, I resize before painting. The relevant code is

```
if (image && !image->isNull())
{
    resize(image->size());
    painter.drawImage(image->rect(), *image, image->rect());
}
```

However, `RenderArea` will stretch too much through other widgets (like buttons and menus). It is contained in a `centralWidget` with a vertical layout. But when I call `centralWidget->adjustSize()` it does not scale everything together, but instead shrinks `RenderArea` t and hides the image.

How do I instruct the central widget as well as the window to scale with the new size of my customized widget? I know I could use a `QLabel` and set its `scaledContents` to be true, but I need a lot of other sophisticated rendering so a simple `QLabel` is not enough.

Comment: Resizing inside paintEvent seems to be invalid (or at least unusual). More than that, a widget generally should not resize itself. You should reimplement `sizeHint()` to make layouts know preferred size of your widget. Call `updateGeometry()` when you want to change `sizeHint()`.

Comment: @PavelStrakhov: I tried your suggestion, removed `resize()`, override `sizeHint()` and called `updateGeometry` before drawing image. No automatically scaling happened. Do I have to call resize from the parent widget?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `sizeHint` function should return recommended widget's size. So `RenderArea` should return image size as its `sizeHint`. When the image is changed the `updateGeometry` function should be called to update a cached `sizeHint` value:

```
class RenderArea : public QWidget 
{
public:
    explicit RenderArea(const QImage &image, QWidget *parent = 0) 
        : QWidget(parent), m_image(image)
    {
    }

    QSize sizeHint() const 
    {
        return m_image.isNull() ? QWidget::sizeHint() : m_image.size();
    }

    void paintEvent(QPaintEvent *event)
    {
        QWidget::paintEvent(event);
        if (!m_image.isNull())
        {
            QPainter painter(this);
            painter.drawImage(rect(), m_image, m_image.rect());
        }
    }

    void setImage(const QImage &image)
    {
        m_image = image;
        updateGeometry();
    }

private:
    QImage m_image;
};
```

When the child widget is resized, the parent widget isn't doing it automatically. Fortunately there is `QWidget::adjustSize` function which lets us to resize the parent widget to fit its content:

```
class Window : public QWidget 
{
    Q_OBJECT

private slots:
    void onImageChanged(const QString &fileName)
    {
        m_area->setImage(QImage(fileName));
        adjustSize();
    }

private:
    RenderArea *m_area;
};
```

Comment: With your code and a lot of trials and errors, I finally made it work. What still baffles me is that I have to use `painter.drawImage(rect(), m_image, m_image.rect());` and cannot use `painter.drawImage(m_image.rect(), m_image, m_image.rect());`. Why? Shouldn't them be the same size since `sizeHint()` returns `m_image.size()`? Also, why does this work only when the central widget has an layout?

Comment: Even if the widget size and the image size are equal initially, the widget size can be changed. For instance an user can change the size of a whole window using mouse. A widget, which doesn't have any layout, doesn't know how to manage a geometry of its children.